# how to bypass makemigration error on django deployment on fly io

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, fly

I am trying to deploy my django app on fly.io
I followed all the steps from this site: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-fly/
On running flyctl launch, I get the following error:

```
    (venv) PS C:\Users\Dell\desktop\re\real_estate> flyctl launch Creating 
    app in C:\Users\Dell\desktop\re\real_estate Scanning source code ? 
    Overwrite "C:\Users\Dell\desktop\re\real_estate\Dockerfile"? No ? 
    Choose an app name (leave blank to generate one): re 
    automatically selected personal organization: dave ? 
    Choose a region for deployment: Chennai (Madras), India (maa) Created 
    app re in organization personal Set secrets on re: SECRET_KEY Creating 
    database migrations Error failed running 
    C:\Users\Dell\desktop\re\venv\Scripts\python.exe manage.py 
    makemigrations: exit status 1
```

I havent made any changes to the database.

I tried running
`python manage.py makemigrations`
It gave following error:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(' ')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

then I tried the following on settings.py file:

```
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["*"]
```

which gave following error:

```
    File "C:\Users\Dell\desktop\re\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\dj_database_url.py", line 88, in parse
    if "?" in path and not url.query:
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS') is None

Comment: @jisson got the same error again i.e:
'''
    Error failed running C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\RE\venv\Scripts\python.exe manage.py 
    makemigrations: exit status 1
'''

Comment: was initial migration success? ( user , auth ....)

Comment: @Jisson on my local machine, it was. but not before launch.